# Configuring mercurial to use a proxy gives error "abort: error: ''"

Tags: proxy, mercurial

Adding a proxy section to my ~/.hgrc file doesn't seem to work, nor does
setting the proxy on the command line; e.g.

```
$ hg --config=http_proxy.host=http://127.0.0.1:8181 incoming
```

The proxy section in my ~/.hgrc file looks like:

```
[http_proxy]
host=http://localhost:8181
```

Instead, I get a not so informative response printed to stderr:

```
abort: error: ''
```

After some investigation, (adding --debug --traceback) I found this error
happens in the keepalive.py file of one of the underlying python library files.

I have Firefox/foxyproxy set up to use this same proxy, and everything works
fine - the port number [and host] is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few minutes I realised my proxy is set up as a socks proxy, and that
mercurial doesn't work with socks proxies. The fact that the section heading is
**http_proxy** was the give-away hint.

I installed [polipo](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/), set it to use the socks proxy as it's parent, and
configured mercurial in the ~/.hgrc file to use this proxy instead.

Everything is working nicely now. (And I've also set firefox to use it instead
as it caches files as required too).